# Inkscape Extension: I can't open the temporary ink_ext_XXXXXX.svg file because it's in use by Inkscape itself

Tags: c#, filestream, inkscape

After figuring out the solution to [my previous problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51650591/inkscape-extension-python-doesnt-invoke-exe) while writing an Inkscape extension, I've now gotten to the part wheren the required information is present in my C#/Mono application.

When I try opening (readonly) the file that Inkscape has temporarily created at `C:\Users\Remote\AppData\Local\Temp\ink_ext_XXXXXX.svg9XL2MZ`, I get the below error:

```
Uncaught exception: System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file C:\Users\Remote\AppData\Local\Temp\ink_ext_XXXXXX.svg9XL2MZ because it is being used by another process.

   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)

   at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)

   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share)

   at my.plugin.InkSVG.OpenFile(String location)

   at my.plugin.Main(String[] args)
```

The code in question:

```
    public XElement OpenFile(string location){
        Debugger.Debug("Opening file: " + location, 1);
        FileStream fs;
        fs = new FileStream(location, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
        // fs = new FileStream( location, FileMode.Open, FileSystemRights.ReadData, FileShare.Read, 4096, FileOptions.None );
        return XElement.Load(fs);
    }
```

Both versions of `fs` being instantiated don't work.
The very first method I had, was simply `XElement.load(location)` but this opens the file using `ReadWrite` permission, something I don't need. Still, using `XElement.load(location)` results in a slightly longer stacktrace, but ultimately the same error.

Using Process Explorer and searching for `ink_ext_XXXXXX.svg` I found two files, both in use by Inkscape - indicating that the most probable cause is Inkscape opens the files but keeps them to itself... Not usefull for when an extension wants to read them too?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I read a file even when getting an "in use by another process" exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4400517/how-can-i-read-a-file-even-when-getting-an-in-use-by-another-process-exception)

Comment: Apparently, `FileShare.ReadWrite` is required. I've altered my code, rebuilt and opened it with Inkscape, and now it processes correctly. Flagged to close as duplicate.